# .on("click", function() not working when link rendered with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

The link below shows a modal and runs an ajax request to render a partial within the modal based on the object id . The link works fine and the modal pops up when the page is fully loaded with an http request, but if I render the link with an ajax request (e.g. a different modal pops up and renders a few of the links) then the js function doesn't run. I tried an alert(); just to check and it doesnt run when its rendered with ajax.

I'm using JQuery 1.9.1, previously the js worked with .live('click'), but that has since been removed. I have also tried .click()

Any ideas? Thank you!

Link

```
<a href="/an-object-id" data-remote=true name="modal">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a[name=modal]").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#mask, #modal").show();
    e.preventDefault();
etc...
```

Comment: What errors are you getting from the javascript console in chrome?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Attach an event handler to a parent element using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and pass the selector as an argument.

Example:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[name=modal]", function(e) {...});
```

which works for dynamically generated elements as well..

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I've just spent far too long trying to figure out how/why my listener wasn't firing!

Answer (score 5):

```
$(document).on("click", "a[name=modal]", function(e) {
    $("#mask, #modal").show();
    e.preventDefault();
etc...
```

Answer (score 4):

use on event delegation..since your link is dynamically generated... click event won't be fired... use document to delegate the event..

```
 $(document).on("click","a[name='modal']", function(e) {
       ..
 });
```

you can go through the [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about `on` delegated events.. it will be much better if you delegate the event with closest element that is present in the document than `document` for better performance

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you need to bind the listener for your click event to something in the DOM that doesn't get altered. `on()` has an optional parameter that lets you filter event triggers to a child element of the item selected as the listener. The simplest is to use `document`, but I prefer to use the closest parent I know I won't change. So, assuming I had this markup:

```
<div id="super-awesome-parent">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Some link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some link text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Some link text</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I could write a `on()` delegate like so:

```
$('#super-awesome-parent').on('click', 'a', function(event){ 
    // ... code 
});
```

Then, any `<a>` elements that are added to `#super-awesome-parent` after the `ready()` event will still be handled by the delegate.